# add multiple empty rows to kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I got an Kendo grid with batch/inline editing like [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing.html) one.
I search for an method to add multiple empty rows to grid.

What I got is an create button (in toolbar) with an own event handler:

```
$('#testBtn', '#grid').bind('click', function (ev) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    //add record using Grid API
    grid.addRow();
    grid.addRow();
});
```

Got anyone an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add items to the grid's data source:

```
grid.dataSource.add({ foo: "foo" });
grid.dataSource.add({ foo: "bar" });
```

Comment: thanks, I got it! I think my problem is the validation:required in the datasource